# How to delete a specific ACLs principal of the topic with help of java code?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
public void deleteReadAcl(AdminClient adminClient, TopicReadRequest readAclRequest) {
        ResourcePatternFilter resourcePatternFilter = new ResourcePatternFilter(ResourceType.TOPIC, readAclRequest.getTopicName(), PatternType.ANY);
        
        AclBindingFilter aclBindingFilter = new AclBindingFilter(resourcePatternFilter, new AccessControlEntryFilter(readAclRequest.getPrincipal(),null,AclOperation.READ, AclPermissionType.ANY));
        Set<AclBindingFilter> bindingFilters = new HashSet<>();
        bindingFilters.add(aclBindingFilter);

        deleteReadAcls(adminClient, bindingFilters);
    }
```

Json after creating ACL in mongo is given below.

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong(104),
"createdDate" : ISODate("2022-04-13T09:39:42.907Z"),
"lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-13T10:07:37.561Z"),
"name" : "topic-request",
"namespace" : "ko",
"environment" : "DEVELOPMENT",
"dc" : "sss",
"configs" : {},
"partitions" : 3,
"replication" : 3,
"cleanUpPolicy" : "delete",
"principals" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : NumberLong(20),
        "name" : "topic-no",
        "accessType" : "READ",
        "service" : "kafka",
        "nonDomainService" : false,
        "consumerGroupName" : "kafka.topic-consume",
        "wildCardEnabled" : false
    }
],
"migratedTopic" : false,
"compactionChecked" : false
```

}

Question Can anyone help me out to delete ACLs of my topic named "topic-request", which is given in principals list with id 20.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
ResourcePatternFilter resourcePatternFilter = new ResourcePatternFilter(ResourceType.TOPIC, topic, PatternType.LITERAL));
Collection<AclBinding> aclBindings = adminClient.describeAcls(new AclBindingFilter(resourcePatternFilter, AccessControlEntryFilter.ANY)).values().get()
      
List<AclBindingFilter> aclToDelete = aclBindings.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.resource().resourceType() == ResourceType.TOPIC && b.entry().operation() == AclOperation.READ)
        .map(b -> new AclBindingFilter(new ResourceFilter(ResourceType.TOPIC, b.resource().name()),AccessControlEntryFilter.ANY))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```